# Read the entire data

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

How can I read the entire incoming data via serial port in Qt. 
For example, if the actual data is FACEBOOK, I am able to read it as only
FACE 
BOOK 
i.e. the data is 'broken'.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by "entire incoming data".

- If it's a block of bytes of a known length, you can use the `readData` method with the expected length.
- If it's a block of unknown length, you probably have some terminating byte or group of bytes, so you have to read available bytes one byte at a time until you read a terminating sequence of bytes (if the termination is an EOL, you have the `readLine` convenience method).